# How can I give numberic keyboard in mobile website in Android (that also has option to switch alphanumeric)?

Tags: html

My question is that how can I give numeric keyboard option that also has option for alphanumeric keyboard. For example, suppose I use

```
<input type="tel" name="child-estimate">
```

It will give me numeric keyboard for mobile but what I need is an option that give users to switch to alphanumeric keyword from numeric. How can I do this?

Comment: beyond changing the input type i don't think there's much else you can do to dictate the keyboard type.. you have to consider some users will have custom keyboards installed on their phones, etc..

Answer (score -1):

a keypad with both numbers and a period shows up.

```
<input type="number" step="0.01">
```

regular old keypad showing up.

```
<input type="text" pattern="\-?\d+(\.\d{0,})?">
```

reference: http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/05/triggering-numeric-keyboards-with-html5.html

Comment: Not what was asked.